# How to do a step-by-step update of images in c# maui

Tags: .net, maui

Let me tell you briefly, I am very poorly versed in MAUI and in fact started using it only for my lab work.
I generate a map and add classes of animals there, each with some logic (it works fine, I checked). The problem is the output of the map itself with the animals.
Each animal class stores a link to an image. I need to output these images as a table or matrix. But when I try to do this, it only outputs the first image of that card, and all the other images are ignored, or else the whole logic runs through first, and then only the first image of the card is output. And I need to display a certain image with every move. Help me, please

**Class for Visualisation**

```
class Visualisation
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyString>> _priorityMap;

        public Visualisation(List<GameObject>[,] gameModel, GamePage gamePage)
        {
            _gamePage = gamePage;
            _gameModelMap = gameModel;
            _priorityMap = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyString>>();
            InitializePriorityMap();
        }

        private readonly List<GameObject>[,] _gameModelMap;
        private readonly GamePage _gamePage;
        private void InitializePriorityMap()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _gameModelMap.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                var row = new ObservableCollection<MyString>();
                for (int j = 0; j < _gameModelMap.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (EasyVisualisation(_gameModelMap[i, j]) != null)
                        row.Add(new MyString(EasyVisualisation(_gameModelMap[i, j])));
                    else
                        row.Add(new MyString("square.png"));
                }
                _priorityMap.Add(row);
            }
        }

        private static string EasyVisualisation(List<GameObject> cell)
        {
            if (cell.Count == 0)
                return null;
            var priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<GameObject, int>();
            foreach (var item in cell)
                priorityQueue.Enqueue(item, item.Priority);

            return priorityQueue.Dequeue().SourceImage;
        }

        async public Task AddImagesToPage()
        {
            var horisontalStackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                BackgroundColor = new Color(255, 255, 255),
            };
            foreach (var row in _priorityMap)
            {
                var verticalStackLayout = new StackLayout
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
                };
                foreach (var item in row)
                {
                    var image = new Image
                    {
                        HeightRequest = 25,
                        WidthRequest = 25,
                        BindingContext = item.ValueString
                    };
                    image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding($"."));
                    verticalStackLayout.Children.Add(image);
                }
                horisontalStackLayout.Children.Add(verticalStackLayout);
            }
            _gamePage.Content = horisontalStackLayout;

            await GenerateImageArrayAsync();
        }

        public async Task GenerateImageArrayAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => UpdatePriorityMap());

        }

        private void UpdatePriorityMap()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _gameModelMap.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _gameModelMap.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (EasyVisualisation(_gameModelMap[i, j]) != null)
                        _priorityMap[i][j] = new MyString(EasyVisualisation(_gameModelMap[i, j]));
                    else
                        _priorityMap[i][j] = new MyString("square.png");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Class with type MyString**

```
public class MyString : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _ValueString;
        public string ValueString
        {
            get { return _ValueString; }
            set { _ValueString = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueString)); }
        }
        public MyString(string value) 
        {
            ValueString = value;
        }
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**GamePage**

```
public partial class GamePage : ContentPage
    {

        public GamePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void StartGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var gameModel = new GameModel();
            var simulation = new Simulation(gameModel.map);
            var visualisation = new Visualisation(gameModel.map, this);
            await visualisation.AddImagesToPage();
            simulation.Start(visualisation);    
        }
    }
```

**Class to start simulation**

```
class Simulation
{
    private readonly Statistics _statistics;
    public static event Action? Update;
    public delegate void AnimalsMove(List<GameObject>[,] map);
    public static event AnimalsMove? Move;
    private readonly int _delay;
    public static int MaxTurns { get; private set; }
    private List<GameObject>[,] _map;

    public Simulation(List<GameObject>[,] map)
    {
        _delay = 200;
        MaxTurns = 100;
        _statistics = new Statistics(map);
        _map = map;
    }

    public async void Start(Visualisation visualisation)
    {
        while (_statistics.TurnsCount < MaxTurns)
        {
            Update.Invoke();
            Move.Invoke(_map);
            Thread.Sleep(_delay);
            await visualisation.GenerateImageArrayAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope for help:)
All I need to do is display the corresponding image on the page each turn

Comment: instead of **binding** the `Image` source, just directly assign it

Comment: What's the code of `GameModel`, `GameObject` and `Statistics`? Could you please post more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Yes, of course, all the code is right here
https://github.com/yungsabirka/OOP_Course_Work_Animals.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented an interesting viewmodel MyString but it was used in a wrong way.

```
public class MyString : BindableObject
    {

        public MyString(string value)
        {
            ValueString = value;
        }

        private string _ValueString;
        public string ValueString
        {
            get
            {
                return _ValueString;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_ValueString != value)
                {
                    _ValueString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem occured from the fact that on every update you are recreating it while the image has bindingContext still set the the initally created one.

So correct way to use it was:

1 AddImagesToPage:

```
image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding($"ValueString"));
```

2 UpdatePriorityMap:

```
if (EasyVisualisation(_gameModelMap[i, j]) != null)
                            _priorityMap[i][j].ValueString = EasyVisualisation(_gameModelMap[i, j]);
                        else
                            _priorityMap[i][j].ValueString = "square.png";
```

There are other issues with the code out of the scope of this question like main thread blocked while creating initial screen and more.

Just a quick tip for a faster startup of the app:

```
private void StartGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_gameModel == null)
            {
                _gameModel = new GameModel(); //avoid recreating if start spam-pressed multiple times
                var simulation = new Simulation(_gameModel.map);
                var visualisation = new Visualisation(_gameModel.map, this);
                visualisation.AddImagesToPage(); //runs on ui-tread inside
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (!visualisation.MapReady) //MapReady set to true by AddImagesToPage 
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(50);
                    }
                    simulation.Start(visualisation);
                });
            }
        }
```

I have created a pull request for your repo with the fixes https://github.com/yungsabirka/OOP_Course_Work_Animals/pull/1

Comment: it works!! thank you very much!! I have been suffering with this problem for several days now, thank you so much again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image's `Source` directly instead of using `Binding`.

Just as follows:

```
                var image = new Image
                {
                    HeightRequest = 25,
                    WidthRequest = 25,
                    BackgroundColor = Colors.Yellow,
                    //BindingContext = item.ValueString
                    Source = ImageSource.FromFile(item.ValueString)
                };
```

You can refer to the whole code of method `AddImagesToPage()`:

```
async public Task AddImagesToPage() 
        {
            var horisontalStackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                BackgroundColor = new Color(255, 255, 255)
            };
            foreach (var row in _priorityMap)
            {
                var verticalStackLayout = new StackLayout
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
                };
                foreach (var item in row)
                {
                    var image = new Image
                    {
                        HeightRequest = 25,
                        WidthRequest = 25,
                        BackgroundColor = Colors.Yellow,
                        //BindingContext = item.ValueString
                        Source = ImageSource.FromFile(item.ValueString)
                    };
                    //image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding($"."));
                    verticalStackLayout.Children.Add(image);
                }
                horisontalStackLayout.Children.Add(verticalStackLayout);
            }
            _gamePage.Content = horisontalStackLayout;

            //await GenerateImageArrayAsync();
        }
```

Besides,I find that the button on page `Button` takes up too much space,you can put it inside of a `VerticalStackLayout` and set special height for it.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Course_Work.GamePage"
             Title="GamePage">
    <ScrollView
        Background="white">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Button HeightRequest="60"
                x:Name="Start"
                Clicked="StartGame"
                FontSize="24"
                BackgroundColor="black"
                Text="Start"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Start the game"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                WidthRequest="200"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>        
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

Since there are lots of pictures to load, so you need to wait for a moment to load these pictures.

Comment: I tried to do something similar, that is, don't bind the images to the links, and at each step of the simulation to generate a new image, but it still didn't work for some reason. until the simulation itself isn't over it didn't output anything